# $12$ Identical balls can be placed into $3$ identical boxes,

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$12$ Identical balls can be placed into $3$ identical boxes, Then find probability that one of

the boxes contain exactly  $3$ balls.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ First we select $1$ bag out of $3$ and then put

$3$ balls into that bag and then put remaining balls into $2$ bag.

Which can be done by $\displaystyle \binom {3}{1}\times 1 \times \binom{1}{1}\times 1 = 3$

bcz here balls are identical . So we can arrange by only one ways.

But my answer is wrong.

plz help me , How can I get correct answer.

Thanks

Comment: Jee Mains 2015? In my opinion the options were wrong.

Comment: Your question is vague. What is the probability distribution of the placement of the balls? In other words, what mechanism was used to put the balls in the boxes? The most obvious way is to take the first ball and choose (at random with uniform probability) which box to put it in, then do that with the second ball, and so on. But there are other ways to place the balls in the boxes. Also, is "success" where *at least one* box has exactly three balls, or *exactly one* box has exactly three balls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the simplest model: One after the other of the balls is thrown at random into one of the boxes $a$, $b$, $c$. There are $3^{12}$ different possible histories for that, all of them equiprobable. The number of histories leading to a particular final content $(r,s,t)$ of the three boxes is the coefficient of the term $a^r b^s c^t$ in the expansion of $(a+b+c)^{12}$, i.e., is given by ${12!\over r!\>s!\>t!}$.

There is the question whether "one of the boxes" means "at least one of the boxes", or "exactly one of the boxes". Since one sentence later they talk about "exactly three balls" my working hypothesis is that "at least one of the boxes" is meant.

For the probability in question we have to consider the contents
$$(3,9,0), (3,8,1), (3,7,2), (3,5,4)$$
each of them in six orders, and $(6,3,3)$ in three orders. The total number $N$ of "admissible" histories is therefore given by
$$N=6{12!\over3!}\left({1\over9!}+{1\over8!}+{1\over 7!\>2!}+{1\over 5!\>4!}\right)+3{12!\over 6!\>3!\>3!}=282\,480\ ,$$
and the required probability $P$ is $$P={N\over 3^{12}}\doteq0.531536\ .$$

Comment: What do you mean by histories?

Comment: @user34304: "One after the other of the balls is thrown at random into one of the boxes $a$, $b$, $c$."

Comment: @Christian Blatter Have you taken both boxes and balls to be distinct ?

Comment: @ViX28: For the counting of cases the balls as well as the boxes are distinct, but in the end I don't care about the numbers on the balls nor about which box(es) contain(s) exactly three balls.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I am not getting why $3^{12}$ since balls are identical. I used to do problem when boxes were different and balls were identical then I used star and bars. Why $3^{12}$ here?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the experiment consists of randomly assigning $12$ balls to $3$ boxes. There are $3^{12}$ ways to do so. We want to find the probability that (at least) one of the boxes contains exactly $3$ balls.
Let us number the boxes $1$, $2$ and $3$, and define $E_i$ as the event that box # $i$ contains exactly $3$ balls. We want to find the probability of the event $E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3$.

$\Pr(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) $
$= \Pr(E_1) + \Pr(E_2) + \Pr(E_3) - \Pr(E_1\cap E_2) - \Pr(E_1\cap E_3) - \Pr(E_2\cap E_3) + \Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)$
$= 3\Pr(E_1) - 3\Pr(E_1\cap E_2) + \Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3) \ \ \ \ \color{blue}{\text{(By symmetry)}}$

We will now find $\Pr(E_1)$, $\Pr(E_1\cap E_2)$, and $\Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)$.

$\displaystyle \Pr(E_1)  = {12\choose 3}\left(\frac{2^{9}}{3^{12}}\right)$

$\displaystyle \Pr(E_1\cap E_2) = {12\choose 3} {9\choose 3}\left(\frac{1^{6}}{3^{12}}\right)$

$\displaystyle \Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3) = 0$

Therefore,
$\Pr(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) $
$= 3\Pr(E_1) - 3\Pr(E_1\cap E_2) + \Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3) $
$=  \displaystyle 3\times {12\choose 3}\left(\frac{2^{9}}{3^{12}}\right) - 3 \times {12\choose 3} {9\choose 3}\left(\frac{1^{6}}{3^{12}}\right)$
$\approx 0.5315$

Here is the code to find the above value. You will also find the computation of the required probability using simulation method in the code:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_g9uaFBlARwEdnL6_1.py

Comment: +1 This is the route I had in mind. You were ahead of me.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the bags are identical.  So if you choose to put $3$ into one bag, then you have to put $9$ into the rest:

```
3 0 9
3 1 8
3 2 7
3 3 6
3 4 5
```

If you continued to 3 5 4 then you would have a duplicate, because the bags are identical.  So there are $5$ ways to have at least $1$ bag with exactly $3$ balls and $4$ ways to have exactly one bag with exactly $3$ balls.

Since 12 is such a small number, it is easier to just enumerate the placements than to try some counting trick (although they do exist) :

```
0 0 12   1 1 10   2 2 8    3 3 6    4 4 4
0 1 11   1 2 9    2 3 7    3 4 5
0 2 10   1 3 8    2 4 6
0 3 9    1 4 7    2 5 5
0 4 8    1 5 6
0 5 7    
0 6 6
```

So there are $7 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 19$ total placement options.

Comment: You’re assuming that the final results are equally likely. This is one interpretation of the problem, and I’ve upvoted it on that basis, but I think that Christian’s is a more likely interpretation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What do you mean by 'assuming final results are equally likely'?

Comment: @user34304: Assuming that, for instance, the `3 4 5` outcome is exactly as probable as the `0 0 12` outcome. This is not the case if, for example, we simply throw $12$ bags in such a way that each has probability $\frac13$ of ending up in each box.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why Christian Blatter's  probablity does not match with DanielV's probability ($5/19$ )?  I think Christian has taken both boxes and balls to be distinct instead of identical. am I right?

Comment: @ViX28: Because Christian and Daniel made different assumptions about the underlying distribution of the outcomes. Christian used the model that he described, of tossing $12$ balls in turn into three boxes, and then removing any identifying features from both. Daniel, on the other hand, assumed that each final distribution is equally likely; this is a possible assumption, but I can’t offhand think of a straightforward model experiment to which it would apply, so I take Christian’s answer to be almost certainly the intended one. \\ No, Christian has assumed that the boxes and the balls ...

Comment: ... are both indistinguishable. His calculation first works with distinguishable boxes and balls, but then he divides by the appropriate factors to get the result for indistinguishable boxes and balls

Comment: ohh thanks for clarifying :) @BrianM.Scott  but still that particular thing bugs me..it may irritate you. but can you again clarify that "equally likely distribution term" .. whats wrong in assuming $(3,4,5)$ is equiprobable as $(0,0,12)$  ..what I think, those are $19$ cases which can happen with equal probability and among which our needs satisfy 5 cases.. so $5/19$ .. how christian has avoided that equally likely thing?

Comment: @ViX28: I can’t think of any natural experimental design that would result in $\{\!\!\{3,4,5\}\!\!\}$ and $\{\!\!\{0,0,12\}\!\!\}$ occurring with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

Probability does not depend on whether the boxes are identical or not because  $(0,0,12)$ has more chances than the event $(4,4,4)$. So we will assume the boxes are different. Now let $A$ be the event that the first ball has exactly 3 balls. Similarly define $B$ and $C$. The required probability is $Pr(A\cup B\cup C) = 3Pr(A)-3P(A\cap B)$,(due to symmetry). Note that $P(ABC)=0$. Twelve identical balls can be distributed in 3 distinct boxes in $\binom{14}{2}= 91$ ways. This can be proved using dots and sticks. If $A$ contains 3 balls then remaining 9 balls can be placed in other two boxes in $\binom{10}{1}=10$ ways. Hence $Pr(A) = \frac{10}{91}.$ Similarly, $Pr(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{91}.$ Hence our required probability is $3\cdot \frac{10}{91}-\frac{3}{91}= \frac{27}{91}.$

Comment: I do believe that if the balls also become distinct then answer of Amit Sir is correct. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score -2):

Required probability
{(3c1*12c3*2 to the power 9) - (3c2*12c3*9c3)} ÷ (3 to the power 12)
this is the right answer

Comment: Please explain further. This on its own sounds like request for downvotes.